# I have an issue with push notifications not coming through in my React Native iOS implementation

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm having an issue with push notifications not coming through in my implementation. Please take a look to see if I've misconfigured something. I've been struggling for two days. Please help.

The version I am currently using is as follows:

```
    System:
      OS: macOS 13.4.1
      CPU: (10) arm64 Apple M2 Pro
      Memory: 96.41 MB / 16.00 GB
      Shell:
        version: "5.9"
        path: /bin/zsh
    Binaries:
      Node:
        version: 18.15.0
        path: /usr/local/bin/node
      Yarn:
        version: 1.22.19
        path: /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
      npm:
        version: 9.5.0
        path: /usr/local/bin/npm
      Watchman:
        version: 2023.07.24.00
        path: /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
    Managers:
      CocoaPods:
        version: 1.13.0
        path: /Users/myname/.gem/bin/pod
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms:
          - DriverKit 22.4
          - iOS 16.4
          - macOS 13.3
          - tvOS 16.4
          - watchOS 9.4
      Android SDK: Not Found
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 2022.1 AI-221.6008.13.2211.9619390
      Xcode:
        version: 14.3.1/14E300c
        path: /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    Languages:
      Java:
        version: 11.0.11
        path: /usr/bin/javac
      Ruby:
        version: 2.7.4
        path: /Users/myname/.rbenv/shims/ruby
    npmPackages:
      "@react-native-community/cli": Not Found
      react:
        installed: 18.2.0
        wanted: 18.2.0
      react-native:
        installed: 0.72.5
        wanted: 0.72.5
      react-native-macos: Not Found
    npmGlobalPackages:
      "*react-native*": Not Found
    Android:
      hermesEnabled: true
      newArchEnabled: false
    iOS:
      hermesEnabled: true
      newArchEnabled: false
```

package.json

```
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.11.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^18.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^18.5.0",
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import <RCTAppDelegate.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <UserNotifications/UNUserNotificationCenter.h>

@interface AppDelegate : RCTAppDelegate <UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
// Splash Screen
#import "RNSplashScreen.h"
// Firebase
#import <Firebase.h>
// Push Notifications
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>
#import <RNCPushNotificationIOS.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

// Required for the registration event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}

// Required for the notification event. You must call the completion handler after handling the remote notification.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}

// Required for the registration error event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error];
}

// Required for the local notification event.
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler
{
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveNotificationResponse:response];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
 

  self.moduleName = @"myappname";
  // You can add your custom initial props in the dictionary below.
  // They will be passed down to the ViewController used by React Native.
  self.initialProps = @{};
  [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
  // Splash Screen
  [RNSplashScreen show];
  // Firebase setup
  // Add the following
  if ([FIRApp defaultApp] == nil) {
    [FIRApp configure];
  }
  // User Notification Center
  UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
  center.delegate = self;

  return YES;
}

// Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler
{
  completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound | UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert | UNNotificationPresentationOptionBadge);
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

@end
```

client: index.ts

```
    /**
     * @format
     */
    
    import {AppRegistry, Platform} from 'react-native';
    import App from './App';
    import {name as appName} from './app.json';
    import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
    import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';
    import PushNotificationIOS from '@react-native-community/push-notification-ios';
    import {Alert} from 'react-native';
    
    messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(async remoteMessage => {
      console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
    });
    
    messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
      console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
    });
    
    PushNotification.createChannel(
      {
        channelId: 'myChannelID', // (Required) Channel ID
        channelName: 'myChannelName', // (Required) Channel Name
        // channelDescription: 'Notification used when the app is running', // (Optional) Default: undefined
        // soundName: 'default', // (Optional) Refer to the `soundName` parameter of the `localNotification` function
        // importance: 4, // (Optional) Default: 4. Integer value for Android notification importance
        // vibrate: true, // (Optional) Default: true. Set to true to create a default vibration pattern.
      },
      (created: boolean) =>
        console.log(`'myChannelID' channel created: '${myChannelID}'`), // (Optional) Callback that returns whether the channel was created, and false if it already existed.
    );
    
    PushNotification.popInitialNotification(notification => {
      console.log('Initial Notification', notification);
    });
    
    PushNotification.configure({
      // (Optional) Called when a token is generated (can be used for registering the token with the server)
      onRegister: function (token: any) {
        console.log('Token for push notifications:', token);
      },
    
      // (Required) Called when a remote or local notification is received or opened
      onNotification: async function (notification: any) {
        console.log('Push Notification:', notification);
        Alert.alert(notification.title, notification.body);
        // if (notification.channelId === 'myChannelID') {
        //   // if (notification.message || notification.data.message) {
        //   //   store.dispatch(
        //   //     userSlice.actions.showPushPopup(
        //   //       notification.message || notification.data.message,
        //   //     ),
        //   //   );
        // }
        // Handle the notification
    
        // (Required) Called when a remote notification is received or opened, or a local notification is opened
        // notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
      },
    
      // (Optional) Called when an action is pressed, invoked when invokeApp is false, and onNotification is invoked (Android)
      onAction: function (notification: any) {
        console.log('Action:', notification.action);
        console.log('Push Notification:', notification);
    
        // Handle the action
      },
    
      // (Optional) Called when there is an error with registration, mainly due to issues with APNS or when the device is a simulator (iOS)
      onRegistrationError: function (err: Error) {
        console.error('Registration Error:', err.message, err);
      },
    
      // iOS only (Optional): Default: all - specify what permissions to request.
      permissions: {
        alert: true, // Allow alert permission
        badge: true, // Allow badge permission
        sound: true, // Allow sound permission
      },
    
      // Whether initial notifications should automatically pop up
      // Default: true
      popInitialNotification: true,
    
      /**
       * (Optional) Default: true
       * - Specifies whether to request permissions (iOS) and tokens (android and iOS).
       * - If not requested, you'll have to call PushNotificationsHandler.requestPermissions() later.
       * - Use the following if you're not using remote notifications or haven't installed Firebase:
       *     requestPermissions: Platform.OS === 'ios'
       */
    
      requestPermissions: true,
    });
    
    
    AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

server: index.js

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

let phoneToken;

process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS =
  "./myapp-firebase-adminsdk-bzbp6-dfgdsgdf.json";

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
  databaseURL: "https://myapp.firebaseio.com/",
});
app.post("/complete", verifyToken, upload.single("image"), (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.file, req.body, res.locals.email, req.headers);
  const test = tests.find(
    (v) => v.testId === req.body.testId && v.success === res.locals.email
  );
  if (!test) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: "fail." });
  }
  test.image = req.file.filename;
  test.completedAt = new Date();
  console.log("token", token);
  if (phoneToken) {
    admin
      .messaging()
      .send({
        token: token,
        notification: {
          title: "Success!",
          body: "Success.",
        },
        android: {
          notification: {
            channelId: "myChannelId",
            vibrateTimingsMillis: [0, 500, 500, 500],
            priority: "high",
            defaultVibrateTimings: false,
          },
        },
        apns: {
          payload: {
            aps: {
              sound: "default",
              category: "myappcategory",
            },
          },
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("Notification sent successfully:", response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error sending notification:", error);
      });
  }
  res.send("ok");
});

app.post("/phonetoken", (req, res, next) => {
  phoneToken = req.body.fcmToken; // Make sure to use the correct key, which should match the key you're sending from the client
  console.log("phoneToken:", phoneToken);

  if (phoneToken) {
    // FCM token is received and valid
    res.status(200).send("Token received and processed successfully");
  } else {
    // FCM token is missing or invalid
    res.status(400).send("Invalid or missing FCM token");
  }
});
```

I have completed uploading the APNs authentication key to Firebase.

I would like to implement push notifications using firebase in react native to ios. How can I do this?
I've been struggling for two days. Please help.